# Some confusion in the Alternating group

Tags: group-theory

I'm currently practising for an algebra exam and I am a bit confused with regards to a certain question. The question states:

Given $a= (2,4)(3,5)$  and $b=(1,3)(4,5)$ find the order of $c=a b$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ I am using the theorem which states that the order of a permutation when written as a product of disjoint cycles is the lcm of its cycle length. So

$$c = (2,4)(3,5)(1,3)(4,5)$$
$$ c= (1,3)(3,5)(2,4)(4,5)$$
$$c= (1,3,5)(2,4,5)$$

I used the commutativity of the disjoint cycles. I worked it out manually but  found that the order does not correspond to 3. I am out of ideas in how to proceed.

Comment: The two 3-cycles $(135)$ and $(245)$ are not disjoint (they both move $5$). $(135)(245)=(13524)$. Actually, that's wrong also. You made another error in swapping the order of the non-commuting cycles $(13)$ and $(35)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cycles are not disjoint.
Just play through all inputs and note that
$$1\stackrel b\mapsto 3\stackrel a\mapsto 5 $$
$$2\stackrel b\mapsto 2\stackrel a\mapsto 4 $$
$$3\stackrel b\mapsto 1\stackrel a\mapsto 1 $$
$$4\stackrel b\mapsto 5\stackrel a\mapsto 3 $$
$$5\stackrel b\mapsto 4\stackrel a\mapsto 2 $$
and from this read off $1\stackrel c\mapsto 5\stackrel c\mapsto 2\stackrel c\mapsto 4\stackrel c\mapsto 3\stackrel c\mapsto 1$, i.e., $c$ is a single 5-cycle $(1, 5, 2, 4, 3)$